# What is the current theory underlying the concept of fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, field-theory, interactions, carrier-particles

When I went to school I was specifically told that fields are material (they occupy some region in space, and they "exist" there) and continuous.

Recently, studying quantum physics I came across the notion of gauge particles which carry all kinds of interactions. From this perspective, if I judge it correctly, fields do not exist - they are essentially these particles being exchanged all the time between the interacting objects.

So, what is the current approach to the concept of fields?